# htaccess: make abc_filename.html to abc/filename (and filename.html to /filename)

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I designed a static webpage in html5 and CSS with 15 german subpages and 15 English pages as well. The English pages all have the name: en_filename.html.
They should be displayed and reached as "tld.com/en/filename", while the german
files should be just "tld.com/filename".

The rewriting of for the german Version works fine. But with the english, I either get Server errors or nothing happens. Here the Code up to now:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

Comment: Hi there, and welcome to StackOverflow! What are the errors you're getting?

Comment: Hi Jeffrey, with the codes the others posted, simply nothing happens. With my trial and error efforts, I mostly got 500 and 404 errors (but I'm not very familiar with htaccess, so I think, maybe I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1):

Add after `RewriteEngine on`

```
RewriteRule ^en\/(.*)$ /en_$1.html [L]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I tried it, but it still keeps the original names and cuts the html off on my server :(

Comment: Try to add a forward slash to your regular expression, so it will be as `^\/en\/(.*)$`

Comment: Thank you Kate, I tried your code, but no success (tried on two different webhosts). I'm not very familiar with .htaccess. But is there a possibiliy, just to write a rewrite for each site, like  RewriteRule ^en_test.html en/test [NC,L]